# Iterators with complex value type: confusion with value_type and reference

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to create a custom iterator wrapper, for example, `enumerate`: given a pair of iterators over type `T`, it would return an iterable over type `std::pair<const int, T&>`, where the first element of the pair will take values 0, 1, 2, so on.

I have a problem figuring out what should be `value_type` and `reference` of my iterator. I want to support two behaviours:

First, referencing values of the underlying sequence:

```
for (auto& kv: enumerate(my_vec)) {
    kv.second = kv.first;
}
```

(sort of `std::iota`);

Second, making a copy of the value:

```
std::vector<int> a{10, 20, 30};
auto copy = *enumerate(a).begin();
a[0] = 15;
std::cout << copy.first << " " << copy.second; // 0 10
```

I'm confused what should be the return type of `Iterator::operator*()`. If it is `std::pair<const int, T&>` then in the second example value will not be copied. If it is `std::pair<const int, T>` then in the first example it is impossible to reference underlying values. What should I do and what should be `value_type`, `reference` and `pointer` typedefs of such iterator?

Here is my attempt to implement it. It supports taking references but not copying.

```
template<typename T>
struct Iterator {
    using TT = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;

    using value_type = std::pair<const int, TT>;
    using reference = std::pair<const int&, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    std::pair<int, T> it;
    Iterator(T iterator) : it(0, iterator) {}
    bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const { return it.second == other.it.second; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { return it.second != other.it.second; }
    reference operator*() { return { it.first, *it.second }; }
    Iterator& operator++() { ++it.first; ++it.second; return *this; }
};
```

P.S. I've just checked, boost::adaptors::index suffers from the same problem and does not copy the value.

Comment: You might be able to pull that off, but it won't be easy. `operator*` would have to return a proxy class (not a straight `pair`). That class's `second` member would in turn be a proxy class, storing both the reference to the underlying element, and a copy of its original value. It would then implement `operator T()` (returning the original value) as well as `operator=` (forwarding the assignment to the reference). I question whether the result is worth all that trouble.

Comment: I don't know why do you have any doubts. Iterable over type `std::pair<const int, T&>` should use `std::pair<const int, T&>` as value and `std::pair<const int, T&> &` as reference. In the second example value will be copied as expected.

Comment: @VTT If my reference type is `std::pair<const int, T&>&`, then I should store it somewhere, shouldn't I? It seems that in such case I will return reference to a temporary which is not good.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Looks doable, but I should indeed think if I really need it. Thanks.

Comment: You definitely should store it somewhere. Also note that returning a new (copied value) as a result of dereferencing iterator may lead to considerable overhead when user only wants to inspect the value and will prevent iterator from working with non-copyable types.

Comment: @VTT I don't yet get it completely but will experiment and return back here in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is similar to that of `std::vector<bool>`, you want to provide a proxy that acts just like a reference but also supports value semantics.

What's different though, is that the types involved aren't restricted, there is two references involved and all sorts of hairiness pops up. The following is a partial implementation and it illustrates some problems you run into

```
#include<iterator>
#include<functional>

template<typename F, typename S, bool defined = true>
struct sfinae_difference_type {};

template<typename F, typename S>
struct sfinae_difference_type<F, S, 
        std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<F>::difference_type, 
                       typename std::iterator_traits<S>::difference_type>>
{
    using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<F>::difference_type;
};

template<typename F, typename S>
class pair_iterator : sfinae_difference_type<F, S>
{
    using Fvalue_type = typename std::iterator_traits<F>::value_type;
    using Svalue_type = typename std::iterator_traits<S>::value_type;
    using Freference = typename std::iterator_traits<F>::reference;
    using Sreference = typename std::iterator_traits<S>::reference;

    F f;
    S s;

public:
    using value_type = std::pair<Fvalue_type, Svalue_type>;

    struct reference
    {
        Freference first;
        Sreference second;

        reference() = delete;
        reference(const reference& other) : first{other.first}, second{other.second} {} 
        reference& operator=(const reference& rhs)
        {
            first = rhs.first;
            second = rhs.second;
            return *this;
        }
        operator value_type() { return {f, s}; }

    private:
        reference(Freference f, Sreference s) : first{f}, second{s} {}
        friend pair_iterator;
    };

    struct pointer
    {
        // similar to reference
    };

    pair_iterator() = default;
    pair_iterator(const pair_iterator&) = default;
    pair_iterator(F f, S s) : f{f}, s{s} {}
    pair_iterator& operator++() { ++f; ++s; return *this; }
    reference operator*() { return {*f, *s}; }
    pointer operator->() { return {f.operator->(), s.operator->()}; }
    bool operator==(const pair_iterator& other)
    {
        return f == other.f && s == other.s;
    }
};
```

You then use it as

```
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::list l{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    pair_iterator begin{v.begin(), l.begin()}, end{v.end(), l.end()};
    for(; begin != end; ++begin)
        std::cout << begin->first << ' ' << begin->second << '\n';
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ced226b5adc0de07)

Some of the immediately obvious problems:

1. Implementation is tedious. Having sfinae friendly type aliases and proper proxies requires copious boilerplate.
2. The semantics of proxies may be confusing. What does copying/assigning one `reference` to another mean? What is `auto is_this_a_copy = *it` supposed to do?
3. What does equality mean? Does both internal iterators have to be equal to be equal? That breaks comparison with end iterators.

All of these have to be hammered out to make it work, and there isn't an easy answer.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. One more question about pointers: as I understand, in this implementation we want to store `reference` instance in `pointer` class and return `&reference` in `operator->()`. Is that correct? If so, why are you passing `addressof(*f)` and not `*f` into pointer's constructor?

Comment: @IvanSmirnov I made a mistake, it should be `f.operator->()` instead to avoid taking address of temporary proxy reference. `pointer` should be nullable and supports arithmetic if it makes sense to, both of which wouldn't be possible with using references